# create video player using three js curved from top and bottom

Tags: jquery, three.js

Is this possible to create a video player using three.js with some curve effect from top and bottom?

[Curved video player](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCYLu.png)

Please refer image in which i saw video player format.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can do this using a [CylinderGeometry](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/geometries/CylinderGeometry) (open ended, with adjusted thetaLength-value) with a [VideoTexture](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/textures/VideoTexture). [Here is an example](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=video#webgl_video_panorama_equirectangular) for using the video-texture.

Something like this:

```
function getVideoTexture() {
  // this is assuming you have the video-element somewhere in your dom
  var video = document.querySelector('video');

  return new THREE.VideoTexture(video);
}

scene.add(new THREE.Mesh(
    new THREE.CylinderGeometry(10, 10, 3, 6, 1, true, -Math.PI/4, Math.PI/2),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: getVideoTexture()})
));
```

Comment: can you please provide codepen as i am not aware about 3js?

Comment: @jpatel Could you try to do something yourself? If you're not aware about Three.js and its basics, then it's a good time to start to learn something yourself.

Comment: can you please update following codepen `https://codepen.io/jignesh2290/pen/GQEaBa`

Comment: @prisoner849 i tried and created codepen so just needs help

Comment: @jpatel you can update your question or ask further questions and you will find someone to help you. Asking us to "just help" without being specific is a bit much.